# Can I use SharedArrayBuffer on iOS?

Tags: ios, security, webassembly, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-opener-policy

According to Mozilla, [there is no browser on iOS supporting the cross-origin-opener-policy,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy) which is one of the [security requirements for enabling a SharedArrayBuffer.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) Does this mean I cannot use a SharedArrayBuffer for any web-application on the iOS platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it says on the Caniuse site that you can enable the feature, but I have found no documentation to this end re: Safari

Comment: Nice catch! I had missed that detail.

Comment: I was hoping to use opencv.js, but this blocked me on Safari on both mac os and iOS and I haven't found any way to enable that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately SharedArrayBuffer was disabled due to Spectre / Meltdown issues, so no, you cannot use it:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=sharedarraybuffer

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, yet hoped there was some special set of requirements that made it possible, as has been done with other platforms. Hopefully, this issue will be rectified soon.

Answer (score 1):

There's a flag you can enable now in Safari:

> Resurrected SharedArrayBuffer and Atomics behind a flag
> (JSC_useSharedArrayBuffer=1) (r269531)

https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/269531/webkit/

Comment: Can you please specify how this flag can be used?

Answer (score 1):

To complete [user3325025](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3325025/user3325025) and [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4633448/alexander)'s answer, you can open Safari with SharedArrayBuffer enabled by typing the following command in the terminal:

```sh
__XPC_JSC_useSharedArrayBuffer=1 open -a "Safari"
```

Here is a list of browsers that support SharedArrayBuffer: https://caniuse.com/sharedarraybuffer

Answer (score 1):

If the user has upgraded to Safari 15.2, SharedArrayBuffer can be enabled with COOP and COEP headers. See [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15_2-release-notes).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30839702)

Answer (score 0):

Safari Technology Preview recently announced it can enable SharedArrayBuffer when the page is cross-origin isolated. https://webkit.org/blog/11975/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-133/

There are certain requirements to enable cross-origin isolation. Learn more here: https://web.dev/coop-coep/